# Generalized Least Squares for linear regression with continous and categorical predictors

Tags: r, multiple-regression, heteroscedasticity, generalized-least-squares

I have a linear regression model in R studio with a continous and a categorical predictor, where the assumption of homoscedasticity is violated:

```
library(stats)
library(lmtest)
set.seed(34)
dat<-data.frame(dv=rnorm(6, sd=1:10),
                categorical.pred = rep(letters[1:4], times=c(400, 800)),
                continous.pred = rnorm(n = 4, sd=1:10))

reg <- lm(dv ~ categorical.pred + continous.pred, data=dat)
bptest(reg)
```

To correct this I have to use the generalized least squares estimator, however I do not know how to proceed when one of the variables in my model is categorical. This source (https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/187387_3ca34c107405427db0e0f01252b3fbdb.html) suggests doing a procedure which involves obtaining the logarithims of my predictors, however for obvious reasons I can't do this to my categorical variable:

```
dat$resi <- reg$residuals
varfunc.reg <- lm(log(resi^2) ~ log(categorical.pred) + log(continous.pred), data = dat)
```

Another option is to use the gls function, however after using it I get an error when I check if the new model is heteroscedastic.

```
library(nlme)
reg.gls <- gls(dv ~ categorical.pred + continous.pred, data=dat, weights=varPower())
bptest(reg.gls)
```

Does anyone know how to proceed in this situation? Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: The GLS residuals will display dynamic variance. The point of GLS is that you account for that. In any event, GLS sounds like the way to go. You may also hear the term “weighted least squares” which is GLS when the residuals are uncorrelated. Another option, particularly if you don’t believe the error terms you be normal (even if with changing variance) is to explore generalized linear models. What is your response variable?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I got my response variable through a principal component analysis. Basically it is the mean of a series of variables that reflect how often the respondent was in touch with different government officials (ranging from 1-never, to 5-once a week). 
Do you know why it is not possible to do the BP test with the GLS model?

Comment: I do not know the exact software issues preventing you from using `bptest`, but it does not seem like a reasonable test when you know or suspect the error terms to have unequal variance. Perhaps the output of `gls` has some metadata telling `bptest` that it shouldn't run.